# How to print 0 to 100 interger without using loop or recursion?

Tags: kotlin

How can i print integer form `0 .. 100` without using any kind of manul **loop or recursion** ?

Comment: A bit vague, `println(0); println(1); ...` is one obvious version, but depending how you define "loop" (forEach for example executes a loop, just using a different syntax), there may be others.

Comment: The close reason here is slightly misleading. There are not really multiple questions here. We used to have a "too broad" reason which included "lacks effort or demonstration of any research" but the correct close reason now would really be "needs details or clarity". Anyway, please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask;](/help/how-to-ask) perhaps you can still edit this into a form which is acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple way would be using

```
IntStream.range(0,101).forEach(::println)
```

Comment: This is looping through the range right?